# Rabbit Mq as Task Runner

Tags: c#, delegates, queue, rabbitmq

I am beginner to RabbitMQ integration. I was doing some experiment with RabbitMq and making it as task runner.

For eg:
Let say I have a class **Tasks**, which has a method called **Foo**()

```
public static string Foo(string test, int id)
{
  return "Admin" + test + id.ToString();
}
```

I have another class called **Producer**, which is declaring Queue for RabbitMQ.

```
using (var conn = factory.CreateConnection())
                {
                    using (var channel = conn.CreateModel())
                    {
                        channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "KKQueue", durable: false, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);
                        var message = "Hello World";
                        channel.BasicPublish(exchange: string.Empty, routingKey: "KKQueue", basicProperties: null, body: Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message ));
                        Console.WriteLine(" [x] Sent {0}", message);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
                }
```

Here we have to pass string as message to consumer.

Consumer class code will consume this queue message

```
using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
                using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
                {
                    channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "KKQueue", durable: false, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);
                    var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
                    consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
                    {
                        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ea.Body);


                        Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);
                    };
                    channel.BasicConsume(queue: "KKQueue", noAck: true, consumer: consumer);
                    Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
```

which is accepting string **message**. Is there a way, by which I can pass put my function call to Producer or Rabbit MQ Queue and let Consumee execute those function calls which are in queue.

I tried by serializing/deserializing the object and then using reflection to invoke the method in consumer code..I am looking for some alternate solution to it by using delegate or something. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no way to do it without serialization, no. Even delegates would need to be serialized. [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) does what you're trying to do and achieves this by serializing the assembly information, class name, method name and arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. You need to "ship" all the assembly code with the message, which is definitively a very bad idea.

You should add you task code library to you consumer app and then use the message to govern the task execution, but without sending the executable code with it.

I personally use MassTransit for this kind of producer/consumer scenario; for example you can have multiple consumers, one for each task, and you can activate the right consumer simply sending a different type of message through RMQ.

Comment: Thanks. I decided to follow serialize/deserialize logic